# Date selection goes to previous day when using momentjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, angularjs, date

I am having a headache when saving dates on my cloud server. Everything works correctly on my local machine. All files are all up-to-date.

I am using Momentjs. When selecting a date from the jquery picker the dates get saved to the previous day.

I have been looking at the post requests and the dates render as such `2014-05-30T23:00:00.000Z` But the date i selected was 31st May 2014 from the jquery picker.

I also noticed that when retrieving data from the server it has UTC on the date object as below:

```
Date1: Tue May 13 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC),
```

But my local machine is in the UK and has

```
Date1: Thu May 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST),
```

In my client side angular code i have the following

```
 $scope.selectedBookingModal.Date1 = moment($scope.selectedBookingModal.Date1).format();
```

Just wondering how i can get the correct date to appear and get saved?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `.zone()`

```
$scope.selectedBookingModal.Date1 = moment($scope.selectedBookingModal.Date1)
                                          .zone('100')
                                          .format();
```

Comment: Have got it working on client side the server result on the req is req.booking= 2014-05-03T00:00:00+01:00 but when i do the conversion on the server i get the following date using moment(booking.Date1).format('YYYY-MM-DD') which gives me 2014-05-02

Comment: you are going to need to use `.zone('100')` there as well. `.zone()` doesn't alter the data, it formats it with an offset.

Comment: will i need the moment timezone library for this?

Comment: moment(booking.Date1).zone(booking.Date1).format('YYYY-MM-DD')) This has just worked as it is using the zone from the date i.e. +01:00